# Invalid Image Path - No Image found at the path refrenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile':'icon.png'"

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ipad, xcode7

During uploading my cordova app to the appstore i am getting this error. Unable to find out the reason or resolution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid Image Path \[...\]", although CFBundleIcons is not present in .plist file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815805/invalid-image-path-although-cfbundleicons-is-not-present-in-plist-file)