# "Invalid Image Path [...]", although CFBundleIcons is not present in .plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to publish a cordova-based app on iOS by doing the following steps:

1. Run `cordova build ios`
2. Open the generated project under `<project>/platforms/ios` in XCode
3. In XCode, edit `<project>-Info.plist` and remove all entries related to icons (`CFBundleIconFile`, `CFBundleIcons`, `CFBundleIcons~ipad`)
4. *Product* > *Build*, then *Product* > *Archive*
5. *Validate...* (and follow wizard) => "Validation Successful"
6. *Upload to App Store...* (and follow wizard) => Error message after upload

> ERROR: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40x40'"

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Previously, I'd had a couple of such error messages and read in other answers that they're related to an entries in `<project>-Info.plist`. I could resolve most with step 3, but this one remained.

There is no entry `CFBundleIcons` in this file anymore, I double-checked by opening the final app archive.

It's also remarkable that **all** related problem descriptions I found online (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165916/error-itms-90032invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-und)) include the code `ITMS-90032` in the error messages, but mine does not. What could be the reason for this?

What causes this error message, or how could I further debug the issue?

Comment: So is the file `AppIcon40x40` in the app bundle?

Comment: @trojanfoe In the resulting .xarchive? Among several other icon and splash screen images, there's one named `AppIcon40x40@3x.png`, but none with exact the name from the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, I haven't found a satisfying explanation for the error message, but I've managed to apply a workaround.

I've created a new icon image file of dimensions 40x40 px and referenced in `config.xml` as follows:

```
<icon src="img/small-icon_40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
```

In `<project>-Info.plist`, I referenced said image under `CFBundleIcons` instead of deleting the whole entry:

[image: screenshot of plist config]

While there still is no file `AppIcon40x40.png` in the resulting app archive, the upload/verification service doesn't seem to care anymore and the submission succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with icon.png. 
It's since I upgraded cordova to 6.0. It the new iOS builder 4.1.0.

you can downgrade ios version to previous one :

```
sudo cordova platform rm ios
sudo cordova platform add ios@3.9.2
```

to check iOS version

```
sudo cordova platforms
```